# How can I ignore a specific message in Gradle's console output?

Tags: gradle, amazon-s3, logging

I am using an s3 repository for many of my dependencies. Upon dependency resolution, I get dozens of wordy warnings:

```
WARNING: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
```

There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/9932) for this, but it doesn't look like it will be solved anytime soon. Meanwhile, my logs are polluted with that message.

What would be the least complex way to exclude that message from Gradle's log output?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to silence/quiet specific logs/loggers. You either silence all logs or live with the warning.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html#sec:choosing_a_log_level

You may be able to use a custom logger instead to filter out the log messages until the issue is addressed: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html#sec:changing_what_gradle_logs

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Unfortunately the guide is very cryptic as of how I would do that. They explain extensively how to *add* logs but nothing about filtering them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of filtering Gradle log messages using their `ContextAwareTaskLogger`, but it's not perfect because:

- it relies on internal Gradle classes so there is no assurance it won't break in future Gradle versions (this works in the latest Gradle at the time of writing, v7.5.1), and
- it only works if the log messages are logged using the `ContextAwareTaskLogger`. I believe this includes the majority of logs made by tasks, but will depend on how the plugin you are using is written.

It works like this (I'm using Kotlin here):

```
// The Gradle task you want to capture the logs of. Most simply obtained using
// tasks.named(). You could apply the same configuration to several tasks by iterating over
// them with eg tasks.forEach()
val task: Task

// A lambda function which applies the desired transformation to each log message
// eg excluding messages based on a regex condition. Return the new message or null if you
// don't want any log message.
// (The underlying interface for this is ContextAwareTaskLogger.MessageRewriter)
val filterLambda: (LogLevel, String?) -> String?

// Then the key command:
(task.logger as ContextAwareTaskLogger).setMessageRewriter(filterLambda)
```

It's possible to use a number of these `MessageRewriter` objects to apply different transformations to the log messages.

Hopefully this will clean up some Gradle logs.